# su - root failed with error "Cannot execute username: No such file or directory"

Tags: login, root, vps

I can't login to root on VPS server. But login to usual user is successful. I've tried to login username and after that change to root by commands `su - root` and `su -`. These commands fail after successful password attempt with message "Cannot execute username: No such file or directory" where username my current username.
I think that error come after my try change username login access with `chsh` command (something like `chsh --shell /bin/sh username`). There is no sudo access on my user. What can I do solve this problem?

Comment: @Kusalananda `su -` either didn't help. Failed with same message

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
su -s /bin/bash username
```

From `man su`:

> `-s`, `--shell=shell`
>
> Run the specified shell instead of the default.  The shell to
>                 run is selected according to the following rules, in order:
>
> - the shell specified with `--shell`
> - the shell specified in the environment variable
>                         `SHELL`, if the `--preserve-environment` option is used
> - the shell listed in the passwd entry of the target
>                         user
> - `/bin/sh`

Update:
Try to check is you have valid `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: didn't help. nothing changed

Comment: @AxborAxrorov Try to check is you have valid `/etc/passwd` file.